# Best simple exponential estimator

Tags: calculus, optimization, approximation

Given smooth enough positive $f(x)$. Find real $c$ such that $$\int_0^1 (e^{cx}-f(x))^2dx$$ is minimized.

Note: it only looks innocent..

Comment: How do you anticipate this being answered? It feels like more information is needed.

Comment: Any additional assumption on $f$? For example, if $f=0$ there is no minimizer (the infimum is $0$, "attained" at $-\infty$).

Comment: I'd like to have $c$ depends on $f$ (or its integrals etc.). Note that $f$ can be negative. For simplicity one can assume positivity.